# Merge Sorting a string array and an int array java

Tags: java, sorting

I've been trying to make a merge sort that sorts a string array and int array together. int[0] is pointing at word[0] so when, say, word[0] shifts to word[2], int[0] should also shift to int[2]. However, my output is different:
a b c d 
4 3 1 3 .
What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] word = {"c", "b", "d", "a"};
    int[] lineNumber = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    mergeSort(word, lineNumber, 0, word.length-1);
    for(int i = 0; i< word.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(word[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(int i =0; i < word.length; i++)
        System.out.print(lineNumber[i] + " ");
}



static void mergeSort(String[] word, int[] lineNumber, int p, int r) {
    int q;
    if(p < r) {
        q = (p+r)/2;
        mergeSort(word, lineNumber, p, q);
        mergeSort(word, lineNumber, q+1, r);
        merge(word, lineNumber, p, q, r);
    }
}

static void merge(String[] word, int[] lineNumber, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q-p+1;
    int n2 = r-q;
    String[] lWord = new String[n1];
    String[] rWord = new String[n2];
    int[] lLineNum = new int[n1];
    int[] rLineNum = new int[n2];
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) {
        lWord[i] = word[p+i];
        lLineNum[i] = lineNumber[p+i];
    }

    for(j=0; j<n2; j++) {
        rWord[j] = word[q+j+1];
        rLineNum[j] = lineNumber[q+j+1];
    }

    i = 0; j = 0;
    for(k=p; k<=r; k++) {
        if(i<n1 && j<n2) {
            if(lWord[i].compareTo(rWord[j]) < 0) {
                word[k] = lWord[i];
                lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
                i++;
            }else 
                word[k] = rWord[j];
                lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
                j++;
            }
            else if(i<n1) {
                word[k] = lWord[i];
                lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
                i++;
            }else if(j<n2){
                word[k] = rWord[j];
                lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
                j++;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your original code enclose `System.out.print(lineNumber[i] + " ");` in braces?

Comment: I'd simply first combine (associate) the string & int into a class (Strint?) then sort that class by String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `merge`. It should look like this:

```
static void merge(String[] word, int[] lineNumber, int p, int q, int r) {
    int n1 = q-p+1;
    int n2 = r-q;
    String[] lWord = new String[n1];
    String[] rWord = new String[n2];
    int[] lLineNum = new int[n1];
    int[] rLineNum = new int[n2];
    int i, j, k;

    for(i=0; i<n1; i++) {
        lWord[i] = word[p+i];
        lLineNum[i] = lineNumber[p+i];
    }

    for(j=0; j<n2; j++) {
        rWord[j] = word[q+j+1];
        rLineNum[j] = lineNumber[q+j+1];
    }

    i = 0; j = 0;
    for(k=p; k<=r; k++) {
        if(i<n1 && j<n2) {
            if(lWord[i].compareTo(rWord[j]) < 0) {
                word[k] = lWord[i];
                lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
                i++;
            }else {
                word[k] = rWord[j];
                lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
                j++;
            }
        } else if(i<n1) {
            word[k] = lWord[i];
            lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
            i++;
        } else if(j<n2){
            word[k] = rWord[j];
            lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in if-else. They are incorrectly structured in your code and look really like this (after fixing indents):

```
if(i<n1 && j<n2) {
    if(lWord[i].compareTo(rWord[j]) < 0) {
        word[k] = lWord[i];
        lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
        i++;
    }else // HERE next 3 lines should be in a {} block
        word[k] = rWord[j];
    lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
    j++;
}
else if(i<n1) {
    word[k] = lWord[i];
    lineNumber[k] = lLineNum[i];
    i++;
}else if(j<n2){
    word[k] = rWord[j];
    lineNumber[k] = rLineNum[j];
    j++;
}
```

In my opinion code would be much cleaner if instead of using two arrays(int[] and String[]) you would use a single array of a class that holds both word and lineNo. Something like:

```
public class WordAndPosition {
  public String word;
  public int lineNo;
}

WordAndPosition[]
```